# Increase of requests count end up with 'Error: socket hang up'

Tags: http, nginx, flask, gunicorn, centos6

Backend service/nginx proxy starts responding 'Error: socket hang up' when there is increased count of requests. The setup is as follows.

OS: CentOS 6

Express JS service -> nginx as a proxy -> flask app run by Gunicorn

JS app sends multiple requests at the same time to the other service, when the request count exceed ~100 it starts to return error responses. If the count is lower everything works fine.

I have followed example configuration of nginx which is in Gunicorn documentation + increasing timeout limits + increasing nginx open files limit. I have also tried keepalive option but the issue still remains. Gunicorn doesn't show any errors.

nginx configuration fragment:

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=0;
    keepalive 100;
}

server {
    listen 5001;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    keepalive_timeout 300;

    root /path/to/app/current/public; # static files

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        # Timeouts
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_send_timeout 300;
        send_timeout 300;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

Error response received from proxy:

```
{ RequestError: Error: socket hang up
    at new RequestError (/home/pm2deploy/apps/app-backend/source/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:14:15)
    at Request.plumbing.callback (/home/pm2deploy/apps/app-backend/source/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:87:29)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/home/pm2deploy/apps/app-backend/source/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
    at self.callback (/home/pm2deploy/apps/app-backend/source/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at Request.onRequestError (/home/pm2deploy/apps/app-backend/source/node_modules/request/request.js:881:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:423:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:165:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
  name: 'RequestError',
  message: 'Error: socket hang up',
  cause: { Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:330:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:423:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:165:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19) code: 'ECONNRESET' },
  error: { Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:330:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:423:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:165:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19) code: 'ECONNRESET' },
  options:
   { method: 'PUT',
     uri: 'http://localhost:5001/transformers/segmentAvg',
     qs:
      { stdMultiplier: 2,
        segmentLeft: 1509366682333,
        segmentRight: 1509367401685 },
     body: { index: [Array], values: [Array] },
     headers: {},
     json: true,
     callback: [Function: RP$callback],
     transform: undefined,
     simple: true,
     resolveWithFullResponse: false,
     transform2xxOnly: false },
  response: undefined }
```

ADDED:

In the OS log was recorded following entry:

```
possible SYN flooding on port X. Sending cookies.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Kernel socket backlog reached the limit and dropped following requests.

Reason: Kernel dropping TCP connections due to LISTEN sockets buffer full in Red Hat Enterprise Linux

#### Increase kernel socket backlog limit

Check the current value:

```
# sysctl net.core.somaxconn
net.core.somaxconn = 128
```

Increase the value:

```
# sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=2048
net.core.somaxconn = 2048
```

Confirm the change by viewing again:

```
# sysctl net.core.somaxconn
net.core.somaxconn = 2048
```

Persist the change:

```
echo "net.core.somaxconn = 2048" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

#### Increase application socket listen backlog

Configuration parameter of uWSGI

```
listen=1024
```

---

This solution was taken from https://access.redhat.com/solutions/30453

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please fully explain your solution. Links off site can break making such a short answer useless to future readers.